What is the potential energy and kinetic energy for capacitor and inductor?
I always thought that $\frac{CU^2}{2}$ is potential energy stored in a capacitor and $\frac{LI^2}{2}$ is kinetic energy stored in inductor. But here and here (page 12) as understand it correctly for parallel $LC$-circuit this definition doesn't work, because the Lagrangian is defined as:
$$L = T-U = \frac{C\dot{\Phi^2}}{2}-\frac{\Phi^2}{2L}$$
so what is correct definition for kinetic and potential energy for capacitor and inductor?

Where in your references does it say or imply that the definitions don't work.

I don't want to state, that they do something wrong, I'm a bit confused about the definition of kinetic or potential energy, because as I know Lagrangian is the difference between kinetic and potential energy, so if in one case $\frac{CU^2}{2}$ is potential energy and in another - kinetic, I'll do mistake in writing Lagrangian

pls include the eq. for a harmonic oscillator and an LC circuit in the question.

In specifying a Lagrangian, one typically specifies the configuration space and generalized coordinates on it. Terms in the lagranigian are often energies in terms of the generalized coordinates and their generalized velocities.

In Lagrangian mechanics the criterion is that the solution to the equation corresponds to a point in variation space such that the derivative of the Action with respect to variation is zero.
Let the variation be a function of a parameter $q$
With $L$ for the Lagrangian of the system:
The criterion to be satisfied: $\frac{d (\int L dt)}{dq} = 0$
Differentiation and integration are linear operations; as a consequence the order of the two terms makes no difference for determining the solution:
$$ \frac{\Phi^2}{2L} - \frac{C\dot{\Phi^2}}{2}  $$
$$ \frac{C\dot{\Phi^2}}{2}-\frac{\Phi^2}{2L}  $$
Either way the equation has the same solution, so there is no necessity to keep track of which is which.






In fact, in the case of harmonic oscillation there is an additional reason that the order of $E_k$ and $E_p$ makes no difference.
In general:
The case where the circumstances are such that the solution to the equation of motion is harmonic oscillation has unique properties.
As example: classical mechanics, the case of Hooke's law:
In the idealized case the restoring force is exactly proportional to the displacement.
With $k$ as coefficient of elasticity, and $x$ for the displacement, the expression for the potential energy:
$$ E_p = \tfrac{1}{2}kx^2 \tag{1} $$
And we have of course the kinetic energy:
$$ E_k = \tfrac{1}{2}m\left(\tfrac{dx}{dt} \right)^2 \tag{2} $$
When generalizing:
A recurring pattern is:
-there is a state, in the case of mechanics the state is position
-there is a first time derivative of that state, in the case of mechanics that is velocity
Analogous:
With $Q$ representing location of charge then $dQ/dt$ corresponds to current. That makes it natural to associate $\tfrac 1 2 L \dot Q^2$ with kinetic energy.
About inductance and energy:
A coil with significant inductance has the following property: the magnetic field that is generated acts in opposition to change of current strength. To get a current going requires the effort of an electromotive force. There is reversal symmetry: the inductance acts in opposition to decrease of current strength. The way that the magnetic field acts is like the way a flywheel acts. To spin up a flywheel takes effort, spinning the flywheel down at the same rate requires the same torque, in opposite direction.

Returning to mechanics:
As we know: in the idealized case Hooke's law gives rise to perfect harmonic oscillation.
Next: evaluate Hamilton's action for half a cycle of the oscillation. Evaluate from one crossing of the point of zero displacement to the next point of zero displacement.
The value of the action $S$:
$$ S = \int_{0}^{\pi} \left(\tfrac 1 2 mv^2 - \tfrac 1 2 k x^2  \right) dt \tag{3} $$
As we know: in the case of harmonic oscillation the potential energy (at extremal displacement) and the kinetic energy (when crossing the point of zero displacement) are in a 1:1 ratio.
Next we examine the derivative of that action with respect to variation.
Application of variation consists of changing the amplitude of the oscillation.
We increase the amplitude by multiplying the displacement with a factor $a$ (This multiplication factor can be arbitrarily close to 1; 1.001, 1.0001, 1.00001, ... )
The unique property of harmonic oscillation is that when you increase the amplitude of the oscillation the kinetic energy and the potential energy remain in that 1:1 ratio.
When the amplitude is enlarged by a factor $a$ both the potential energy and the kinetic energy enlarge by a factor $a^2$; the two enlarge in the same proportion.
When the amplitude is increased: the total energy increases, but the ratio of kinetic energy and potential energy remains 1:1
It follows:
For every amplitude: when you increase the amplitude the derivative of Hamilton's action with respect to change of amplitude is zero.

The order of $E_k$ and $E_p$ makes no difference
In the case of:
-harmonic oscillation
-evaluation of sine function from $0$ to $\pi$
Then using ($E_p-E_k$) instead of ($E_k-E_p$) makes no difference, the derivative with respect to change of amplitude is zero either way.



In the above discussion I made the statement:
'Application of variation consists of changing the amplitude of the oscillation'
The same stated in different words:
The scope of the variation is exclusively variation of the position coordinate. The solution to the equation is a function that gives position as a function of time; it is inherent to the mathematics of calculus of variationsis that there is no variation of the time coordinate.
So: differentiation with respect to variation boils down to differentiation with respect to position coordinate.

thank you for your answer) do you mean $q$ for the charge? and why it is variation?

@Curious, In Lagrangian mechanics, “$q$” is often used to denote a generalized configuration coordinate. Terms in the lagrangian are then expressed as functions of such $q$’s and  $\dot q$’s. Electric charge (displaced from one capacitor plate to the other) could be chosen as a configuration coordinate, whose mechanical analogy would be a displacement.

thank you so much for your very detailed addition) could you please clarify the following: it is clear that increasing the amplitude of oscillation doesn't change the ratio of kinetic energy to potential energy, but increasing both of them will increase the Hamiltonian, my question is how do you take derivative in this case?

@Curious In the past hours I went back in multiple times to correct errors in the mathematical expressions. The reasoning was correct, but I fumbled several of the expressions. I also added discussion of which energy term to see as a form of potential energy and which term to see as a form of kinetic energy. It's a natural attribution.

According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LC_circuit
the equation for current in an LC-circuit is:
$$ \ddot I(t) + \frac 1 {LC} I(t) = 0 $$
comparing that with a harmonic oscillator:
$$ m\ddot x(t) + kx(t) = 0 $$
then we would identify:
$$ \frac 1 {LC} \leftrightarrow \frac k m $$
so $L^{-\frac 1 2}$ and $C^{-\frac 1 2}$
contribute equal parts to the potential energy of the current.
Nevertheless, one can liken static stored charge $Q$ in a capacitor ($1/C$) with energy:
$$ U_c = \frac 1 2 \frac{Q^2} C $$
to static stored energy in a compressed (by $x$) spring ($k$):
$$ U_k =\frac 1 2 kx^2 $$
The former has the ability move charge, while the latter has the ability to move mass.
Meanwhile, the energy stored in an inductor ($L$) is:
$$ T_L = \frac 1 2 L \dot Q^2 $$
while looks like the kinetic energy in a moving mass:
$$ T_M = \frac 1 2 M\dot x^2 $$
Of course a moving mass stays in moving unless acted on by an external force.  Meanwhile moving charge, in an inductor, tends to stay in moving too.

Kinetic energy is $1/2mv^2$ of a moving mass. The kinetic energy of a current is tiny. First, electrons are $1800$ times lighter than protons and neutrons. And only a fraction of the electrons of copper are conduction electrons. So the moving mass is far far less than the mass of the wire.
Second, the motion of electrons in the current is mostly random thermal motion with a small drift velocity in the direction of the current. The drift velocity is really slow. It might take a week for an electron to travel around a small circuit.
The speed of electricity is far higher. Think of a water pipe. If you open a valve, water almost immediately begins to flow through the whole pipe. One drop pushes on the next, which pushes on the next. And a drop is pushed out the far end. No drop traveled the length of the pipe. It is the same will electricity.
Electrons exert very strong electric and magnetic forces on each other. These forces transmit energy. If you have enough energy to push an electron in one end of a wire, the electron pushed out the far end has enough energy to do something useful.
Potential energy is energy of a spring. If you add potential energy to a spring by pushing its ends together, the spring can give it back by pushing on a mass. The mass gains kinetic energy as the spring loses potential energy.
A spring is typically made of solid steel. It doesn't compress very much when you push on it, but it does compress some. You have to make springs out of thin leaves or coils to make it noticeably springy. But even a rod compresses microscopically. That is how sound travels down it.
Electrons in a wire are a really stiff spring like a steel rod. It transmits energy but doesn't store much.
A capacitor is like a thin leaf spring. Electrons pile up one one plate and leave the other. The distances are much larger than for neighboring electrons in a wire. So the forces are much less. You can pile up significant numbers of electrons (significant charge) and accumulate significant potential energy.
The potential energy is the work needed to compress the spring. You can calculate it different ways, but it is always equivalent to $W = Fd$.
$$W = Fd = nqEd = QEd$$.
$E \propto Q$, so $W \propto Q^2$. A convenient name for the constant of proportionality the capacitance, $C$. (I am glossing over a factor of $2$, like the $1/2 kx^2$ for a spring.) So
$$W = 1/2CQ^2$$
Or you can work with voltage, which is the potential energy per unit charge.
$$W = QEd = QV$$
$Q \propto E \propto V$, so $W \propto V^2$. You get
$$W = 1/2V^2/C$$
An inductor is similar, but different. Moving electrons generate magnetic fields. For ordinary currents, the field isn't all that big around a single wire. If you make a coil, you add up the magnetic fields from the individual wires.
The force from the magnetic field is less intuitive. It tends to keep the electrons moving as they are. Once you have a current, you have a magnetic field. If you reduce the energy pushing electrons into the end of the wire, you would expect the electrons coming out the other end to have reduced energy. But the magnetic field pushes them along, keeping the energy higher than it would be. The current doesn't drop immediately. It drops as the energy of the magnetic field is used up.
When you first turn on the circuit, there is no current. You would expect current to begin to flow immediately. But it builds up. As it does, energy goes into creating a magnetic field.
This gives something of an idea of how it works. But to get it right, you need to follow the math. Math derivations are more rigorous. It is easy to get intuition wrong. Also math gives numerical answers. It tells you exactly how current grows or decays.

thank you so much for your very comprehensive answer!)  but could you please tell me what is the "recipe" for deciding in which case $\frac{CU^2}{2}$ is kinetic energy and in which case it is potential energy? for now it looks like guessing or fitting the answer...

First, let me collect my earlier comments here:

In specifying a Lagrangian, one typically specifies the configuration space and generalized coordinates on it. Terms in the lagrangian are often energies in terms of the generalized coordinates and their generalized velocities.
@Curious, In Lagrangian mechanics, “$q$” is often used to denote a generalized configuration coordinate. Terms in the lagrangian are then expressed as functions of such $q$’s and $\dot q$’s. Electric charge (displaced from one capacitor plate to the other) could be chosen as a configuration coordinate, whose mechanical analogy would be a displacement.


To address your question more directly, let me quote from your reference https://arxiv.org/pdf/2312.05329

2.2 Constructing the Lagrangian: inductive and capacitive branches
For a given electrical circuit and its graph, the first task is to write down the Lagrangian of the circuit in terms
of our chosen variables $\Phi_b(t)$ and their time derivatives
$\dot \Phi_b(t)$. These variables will be the analog of positions and
velocities in the mechanical setting. We can obtain the Lagrangian by considering the potential or kinetic energy
stored in each conservative element. For the circuit elements that we consider in this chapter, the Lagrangian will
be of the form
$${\cal L} = T(\{\dot \Phi_b(t)\}) − U(\{ \Phi_b(t)\}),$$
where $T$ plays the role of the kinetic energy and $U$ the role of the potential energy.
...
The reason to use branch variables in ${\cal L}$ is that energy is stored in branches (not in nodes), but, as we will see later, it is also possible to obtain formulations in terms of independent node variables.

(emphasis mine)

So, the point is

one first chooses a "space of configurations" and often a choice "generalized coordinates" (not necessarily displacements-measured-in-meters-in-the-real-world, but mathematically treated as if they were ) and their associated "generalized velocities".

one next writes down a Lagrangian function---often (but not necessarily) as $\cal L=$("T"$-$"U")

where "U" is a function that depends on the generalized-coordinates alone (treated as "a generalized potential energy")
and "T" is an often quadratic function that depends on the generalized-velocities  (treated as a "generalized kinetic energy") and maybe generalized-coordinates,
but where "U" and "T" are not necessarily the physical potential and kinetic energies, but would be in a mechanical analogue with the chosen configuration-coordinates as displacement variables.


one uses the Lagrange equations to get the "equations of motion" of the system in those generalized coordinates and velocities. One can also get a "generalized [canonical] momentum" using the usual definition $p=\displaystyle \frac{\partial {\cal L}}{\partial \dot q}$.


In your system [in which both the potential energy and kinetic energy are quadratic], following the strategy suggested in the quote,
there may be benefit to choosing "branch variables" as configuration variables,
as well as alternatively choosing "node variables" as configuration variables.

In an antenna energy exchange occurs between its electric field and moving current.  The dynamics of a half wave dipole are similar to sloshing water in a bathtub.  At the instant the water stops moving the energy is potential, piled water at one end and less at the other; when the water is moving fastest there is equal water at the ends, the energy has converted to kinetic. The fact that this energy exchange repeats with only slowly diminishing amplitude implies the two different energy states are equal. In the dipole antenna, as in the bathtub, the center section carries the most current, while the ends get the most voltage or hydraulic pressure.
